# Cannot login using listener name on secondary server after failover

Tags: sql-server, listener, high-availability, alwayson

i am not able to connect using AG listener name after fail-over to secondary server. SSMS gives error 18456 ( login failed for user ''). I have tested following scenarios:
- 1st server is working as expected with listener. Problem occurs when second server becomes primary
- Can login using instance name with same user but not when use listener name
- Pinging listener name from both servers return correct IP address

Not sure what else to check. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

May I know when you connected to listener name, what kind of authentication you were using?  SQL Authentication or Windows Integration authentication?

If it was windows authentication, was that local windows user or AD user? 
If it was SQL Authentication, can you check if the SQL logins has the same SID? Please run the following on both primary replica and secondary replica and post here:

```
USE <your db name>
SELECT name, sid FROM sys.sysusers WHERE name = 'your user name' 
GO 
USE MASTER 
SELECT name, sid FROM sys.sql_logins WHERE name = 'your user name' GO
```

Per my experience, I suspect you were using SQL Authentication. Let me know!